# Poor performance with big tables on explorer 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

I have a table with 2K+ rows in it.
In chrome, firefox and IE8,9 it works fine, but in IE 7 the user will have to wait 30s or so...

The table is built using .NET's GridView.
According to some reading I've made, setting the width of the cells myself, rather than let the browser calculate it for each TD is better approach, and that what I've done...

What can I do to improve the loading time of the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if any user would be interested to see all the 2K rows on a single page at once.. Why don't you try using Paging for the Grid to show may be 100 rows per page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you should do anyway is add paging and avoid showing 2K records on the same page inside a Grid. This should be done anyway also on the database access level, pointless to query all those rows out of the database, transport them to the web server and render them in the same page. Set up grid paging and limit the page size to something smaller usually between 20 to 100 depends on the context.

For a step by steg guide on how to enable paging, see here:

[GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Paging and Sorting the GridView's Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)

Comment: I suggest that you merge your comment and answer. No reason to have the information in two places. +1 either way.

Comment: The problem was that the client demanded a non-paging table... against any UI logic, I know... I've just wanted to know if there is some sort of optimization I could do in order to improve loading time... thanks anyway.

Comment: You could also try to set minimum supported browser as IE8 or disable the grid viewstate. all what works for you but the only optimal solution is paging. or you replace the loading method with an ajax loading and you load 100 rows at time putting them on grid bottom as they arrive ank keep doing so until you got all of them.

Comment: Do you think that using other grids components, such as JQgrid may give me better results? or the bottle neck is the HTML parsing by the browser (only in IE 7) and nothing else can really improve the performance of displaying few k's of rows at once?

Answer (score 0):

Like what Davide suggested, showing 2k rows is alot, and either cutting down that number or using something like http://www.datatables.net/ that can split it into multiple pages or all on one page but only loads the pages you can see.

It also supports async loading, so the users get a mucher better experience